# Windows 10 will not boot following Fedora install

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, fedora, operating-systems

I installed Fedora 25 precisely following Fedora's own suggested instructions, using a Live USB Stick (Fedora image on a flash drive) to boot into Fedora, and then install the operating system in 90GB of space cleared by Windows 10 from my Windows 10 partition. Fedora works beautifully. But Windows, not so much.

On turning on the computer, I see three options:

`Fedora (4.8.6-300.fc25.86_64) 25 (Workstation Edition)`

`Fedora (0-rescue-a5beeabae48d4518810d3d62dbd82809) 5 (Workstation Edition)`

`Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)`

When I hit the first one, Fedora loads, and it's just fine. The second option looks like a recovery boot for Fedora, so I haven't tried that. When I try the third one, Windows Recovery starts, which is interesting because there was nothing wrong with Windows before installing Fedora, and I'm inclined to think there's nothing wrong with it now, Fedora just "unlinked" (right word?) the actual Windows 10 OS, instead thinking the recovery partition was the OS, and now I have no way of getting into the OS.

One of the options when Recovery finishes doing its thing is to Continue to Windows 10, but that just restarts the computer, so I still can't get into the actual Windows OS.

So far I've tried changing BIOS settings, looking online for an answer, and all kinds of other things. Unfortunately, I don't have a backup, and I really need to be able to get into my windows machine. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: As windows boot, keep pressing f8 (before recovery screen). You shuold be able to try safemode. it's also worth disabling automatic restart, should you get into the F8 Screen.

Comment: There is no "before recovery screen", running `Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)` goes *directly* to recovery

Comment: Are you saying there is NO time between you selecting the OS, and the recovery screen appearing?

Comment: @StevenDavison None at all. Here's a demo: http://imgur.com/gallery/hqJppX2